# setText in AsyncTask android

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I need to update a textView with data from remote db MYSQL, but I have a problem when I try to update the textview in AsyncTask.I tryed everything but it always give me a void textview.
This is my code:

```
public class Credits extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button home;
private String user;
public TextView totSpesa;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String URL = "http://**********/services.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_ERROR_MESSAGE = "error_msg";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_credits);
    user=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("id", ""); 
    totSpesa= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tot_spesa);

    home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_btn);

    home.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.home_btn:
        Intent i = new Intent(Credits.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptCredits extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Credits.this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //Intent in = getIntent();
        //user = in.getStringExtra("id");
        String tot_spesa="";
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "get_credits"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    URL, "POST", params);

                tot_spesa=json.getString("tot_spesa");    


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tot_spesa;



    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String tot_spesa) {

        totSpesa.setText(tot_spesa);   

    }

}


}
```

Comment: are you sure that no exception is throwing inside the doInBackground?

Comment: Yes,  I also try to set a text in postexecute with no result

Comment: But where starting `AsyncTask ` using `new AsyncTask().execute("")` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Rivas202: add `new AsyncTask().execute("")` in `onCreate` method after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_credits);` and for more details see [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...))

Comment: oh yes, I forget to call it, thank you very much!

Comment: one last thing, if I want to return an array from doInBackground?

Comment: You can only return an array to onPostExecute method.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't think you're actually launching your `AsyncTask`.

Try to do :

```
new AttemptCredits().execute(user);
```

In `onCreate`,
and get your user in `doInBackground` with

```
user = args[1];
```